# SignalR Web Sockets IIS8 Server 2012 - "Not a web socket request"

Tags: .net, signalr

I have a site using SignalR(rc1) on IIS8/Windows Server 2012.  It runs pretty ok, except that it appears to be falling back to serverSentEvents and I want web sockets real bad.

I see a signalr/negotiate GET with a 200 response:
{"Url":"/signalr","ConnectionId":"b274f430-7d19-40b8-b448-4ea346042547","KeepAlive":15.0,"DisconnectTimeout":40.0,"TryWebSockets":true,"WebSocketServerUrl":null,"ProtocolVersion":"1.1"}

Then I see a signalr/connect GET with a 500 and an exception "Not a web socket request":

www.xxxxxx.com/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionId=56dc6212-387c-43b2-8555-6f8787c9cf17&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22orderhub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22systemhub%22%7D%5D&tid=6

Trying to load the link directly gives the following ysod:
[image: Not a web socket request]

Then it starts using serverSentEvents!  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? Obviously you can't follow the link and expect it to be a websocket request...

Comment: Firefox 18 and chrome 23.  When viewing the network tab of chrome the connect request has no debug or response info at all.  When viewing in Firefox it shows the not a websocket 500.

Comment: Viewing it in the browser will never show as a websocket request so that's expected. But chrome 23 and firefox 18 should be correctly using websocekts. Do you have a public link?

Comment: I have a public site, but it's password protected.  I just created an account for you.  I'm in the jabber room.  Can I send the user/password there?

Comment: Our server is behind a loadbalancer. The loadbalancer only accepts HTTP requests on port 80. I've updated the loadbalancer to accept all types of TCP connections on port 80.

Result: **WebSockets now work on our site!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our server is behind a loadbalancer. The loadbalancer only accepts HTTP requests on port 80. I've updated the loadbalancer to accept all types of TCP connections on port 80.

**Result: WebSockets now work on our site!**